# Invalid Token Error

Tags: c#

Here is my code that I am getting an error on:

This code is for a Windows Form to verify that the user enters information into text boxes

```
private void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(validateform())
    {
        return;
    }
}

private bool validateform()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCustomerID.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Customer ID is required.");
        return false; 
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtProductID.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Product ID is required.");
        return false; 
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtOrderQty.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Order Qty is required.");
        return false; 
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUnitPrice.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unit Price is required.");
        return false; 
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSubTotal.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sub Total is required.");
        return false; 
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTaxAmount.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Tax Amount is required.");
        return false; 
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTotalDue.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Total Due is required.");
        return false; 
    }

    return true; <<<Return is underlined and the error reads:  Invalid token 'return' in  class, struct, or interface member declaration
}
```

Comment: What error and where is it in the code?

Comment: It is an invalid token error and it is in the bottom where the code reads return true;

Comment: Just formatted your code... and noticed you were missing a `{` near the end of the function. That might be it.

Comment: You're missing a `{`.

Comment: Where am i missing a { ?

Comment: the last if is missing a {

Comment: what line of code am i missing it from

Comment: It's hard to say the exact line, but it is after this line: `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTotalDue.Text))` You are missing the openning bracket.

Comment: I think the code has changed, is this your code??

Comment: yes thats my code, but now I have a different error

Comment: @SuperOli fixed the error in your code, rather than leaving it there for you to see. Not sure that was a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an open brace after your last if statement. This means that the closing brace is actually closing the class, and therefore your last return statement is outside of the class.

Just add the opening brace:

```
    // Other code here
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTotalDue.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Total Due is required.");
        return false; 
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: When I added the curly bracket to the if statement, the last curly bracket is underlined and it says there is an } expected.